# convex optimization: simple conjugate function example

Tags: convex-optimization

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
                      0 &\text{ if }  |u| \le 1 \\
                  |u|-1 &\text{ if }  |u| \gt 1 
                        \end{cases}
$$
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 
                      u^2 &\text{ if } |u| \leqslant 1 \\ 
                      2|u|-1 &\text{ if }  |u| > 1 
                         \end{cases}$$

$$f^*(s) = \sup \left( \langle s,x\rangle -f(x)\right)$$

I am studying this for the first time.
To learn from easier examples,
Please help me to find the conjugate functions of $f(x),g(x)$

Thank you.

Comment: You *really* need to read about how to use the cases environment! Please take moment to see the TeX edits.

Comment: Good. I hope someone could let me get through it smoothly then :)

Comment: Thanks Pedro. It is resolved at the moment. I will try to learn more on TeX.

Comment: In your case, you have $f(x) = \max(0, |x| - 1)$ and $g(x) = \max(2|x| - 1, x^2)$. Using the above, you can re-formulate the supremum computation, in both cases, as easy to solve convex optimization problems. I believe you should try it first, before looking at a complete answer.